# Does jQuery Easing ship with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I remember someone telling me that the features of the [Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) plugin may now be included in the jQuery core, or in jQuery UI. Is that true? Is the plugin still needed if using the current version of jQuery?

Comment: test it out. http://jsfiddle.net and try to use the plugin with just the base script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two easing modes included in the jQuery library. From the documentation:

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default,
>   called `swing`, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called
>   `linear`. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably
>   [the jQuery UI suite](http://jqueryui.com/).

Source: http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Here is a [showcase of easing modes included in jQUery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#easing)

Comment: So you are saying regular jquery only comes with "swing" and "linear" and in order to get more easing options we must also import jQuery UI?

Comment: @DustinPoissant: Yes, or possibly some other library that offers easings for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/GSHu7/

Looks like it.